# Trying to Optimize Python API read script

Tags: python, api, loops, optimization

So I am creating a script to communicate to our API server for asset management and retrieve some information. I've found that the longest total time portion of the script is:

{method 'read' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects}

Currently we're pulling information about 25 assets or so and that specific portion is taking 18.89 seconds.

Is there any way to optimize this so it doesn't take 45 minutes to do all 2,700 computers we have?

I can provide a copy of the actual code if that would be helpful.

```
import urllib2
import base64
import json
import csv

# Count Number so that process only runs for 25 assets at a time will be
# replaced with a variable that is determined by the number of computers added
# to the list
Count_Stop = 25

final_output_list = []


def get_creds():
    # Credentials Function that retrieves username:pw from .file
    with open('.cred') as cred_file:
        cred_string = cred_file.read().rstrip()
        return cred_string
        print(cred_string)


def get_all_assets():
    # Function to retrieve computer ID + computer names and store the ID in a
    # new list called computers_parsed
    request = urllib2.Request('jss'
                              'JSSResource/computers')
    creds = get_creds()
    request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(creds))
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    # At this point the request for ID + name has been retrieved and now to be
    # formatted in json
    parsed_ids_json = json.loads(response)
    # Then assign the parsed list (which has nested lists) at key 'computers'
    # to a new list variable called computer_set
    computer_set = parsed_ids_json['computers']
    # New list to store just the computer ID's obtained in Loop below
    computer_ids = []
    # Count variable, when equal to max # of computers in Count_stop it stops.
    count = 0
    # This for loop iterates over ID + name in computer_set and returns the ID
    # to the list computer_ids
    for computers in computer_set:
        count += 1
        computer_ids.append(computers['id'])
        # This IF condition allows for the script to be tested at 25 assets
        # instead of all 2,000+ (comment out other announce_all_assets call)
        if count == Count_Stop:
            announce_all_assets(computer_ids, count)
    # announce_all_assets(computer_ids, count)


def announce_all_assets(computer_ids, count):
    print('Final list of ID\'s for review: ' + str(computer_ids))
    print('Total number of computers to check against JSS: ' +
          str(count))
    extension_attribute_request(computer_ids, count)


def extension_attribute_request(computer_ids, count):
    # Creating new variable, first half of new URL used in loop to get
    # extension attributes using the computer ID's in computers_ids
    base_url = 'jss'
    what_we_want = '/subset/extensionattributes'
    creds = get_creds()
    print('Extension attribute function starts now:')
    for ids in computer_ids:
        request_url = base_url + str(ids) + what_we_want
        request = urllib2.Request(request_url)
        request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(creds))
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
        parsed_ext_json = json.loads(response)
        ext_att_json = parsed_ext_json['computer']['extension_attributes']
    retrieve_all_ext(ext_att_json)


def retrieve_all_ext(ext_att_json):
    new_computer = {}
    # new_computer['original_id'] = ids['id']
    # new_computer['original_name'] = ids['name']
    for computer in ext_att_json:
        new_computer[str(computer['name'])] = computer['value']
        add_to_master_list(new_computer)


def add_to_master_list(new_computer):
    final_output_list.append(new_computer)
    print(final_output_list)


def main():
    # Function to run the get all assets function
    get_all_assets()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Function to run the functions in order: main > get all assets >
    main()
```

Comment: that wouldn't be helpful, that would be _necessary_. Otherwise why tagging the question as "python" ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Added the code snipped minus the URLs as they're internal

Comment: I'll let someone else try to answer. At least it's possible now.

Comment: You have lot of network requests. Please log time around requests. If they take most of time, then you need to reduce number of requests in order for this to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'd _highly recommend using the 'requests' module over 'urllib2'. It handles a lot of stuff for you and will save you many a headache.

I *believe* it will also give you better performance, but I'd love to hear your feedback.

Here's your code using requests. (I've added newlines to highlight my changes. Note the built-in .json() decoder.):

```
# Requires requests module be installed.:
# `pip install requests` or `pip3 install requests`
# https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/
import requests

import base64
import json
import csv

# Count Number so that process only runs for 25 assets at a time will be
# replaced with a variable that is determined by the number of computers added
# to the list
Count_Stop = 25

final_output_list = []

def get_creds():
    # Credentials Function that retrieves username:pw from .file
    with open('.cred') as cred_file:
        cred_string = cred_file.read().rstrip()
        return cred_string
        print(cred_string)

def get_all_assets():
    # Function to retrieve computer ID + computer names and store the ID in a
    # new list called computers_parsed


    base_url = 'jss'
    what_we_want = 'JSSResource/computers'
    request_url = base_url + what_we_want


# NOTE the request_url is constructed based on your request assignment just below.
# As such, it is malformed as a URL, and I assume anonymized for your posting on SO.
#    request = urllib2.Request('jss'
#                              'JSSResource/computers')
#

    creds = get_creds()


    headers={
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(creds),
    }
    response = requests.get( request_url, headers )
    parsed_ids_json = response.json()


    #[NO NEED FOR THE FOLLOWING. 'requests' HANDLES DECODES JSON. SEE ABOVE ASSIGNMENT.]
    # At this point the request for ID + name has been retrieved and now to be
    # formatted in json
    # parsed_ids_json = json.loads(response)


    # Then assign the parsed list (which has nested lists) at key 'computers'
    # to a new list variable called computer_set
    computer_set = parsed_ids_json['computers']
    # New list to store just the computer ID's obtained in Loop below
    computer_ids = []
    # Count variable, when equal to max # of computers in Count_stop it stops.
    count = 0
    # This for loop iterates over ID + name in computer_set and returns the ID
    # to the list computer_ids
    for computers in computer_set:
        count += 1
        computer_ids.append(computers['id'])
        # This IF condition allows for the script to be tested at 25 assets
        # instead of all 2,000+ (comment out other announce_all_assets call)
        if count == Count_Stop:
            announce_all_assets(computer_ids, count)
    # announce_all_assets(computer_ids, count)

def announce_all_assets(computer_ids, count):
    print('Final list of ID\'s for review: ' + str(computer_ids))
    print('Total number of computers to check against JSS: ' +
          str(count))
    extension_attribute_request(computer_ids, count)

def extension_attribute_request(computer_ids, count):
    # Creating new variable, first half of new URL used in loop to get
    # extension attributes using the computer ID's in computers_ids
    base_url = 'jss'
    what_we_want = '/subset/extensionattributes'
    creds = get_creds()
    print('Extension attribute function starts now:')
    for ids in computer_ids:
        request_url = base_url + str(ids) + what_we_want


        headers={
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(creds),
        }
        response = requests.get( request_url, headers )
        parsed_ext_json = response.json()


        ext_att_json = parsed_ext_json['computer']['extension_attributes']
    retrieve_all_ext(ext_att_json)

def retrieve_all_ext(ext_att_json):
    new_computer = {}
    # new_computer['original_id'] = ids['id']
    # new_computer['original_name'] = ids['name']
    for computer in ext_att_json:
        new_computer[str(computer['name'])] = computer['value']
        add_to_master_list(new_computer)

def add_to_master_list(new_computer):
    final_output_list.append(new_computer)
    print(final_output_list)

def main():
    # Function to run the get all assets function
    get_all_assets()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Function to run the functions in order: main > get all assets >
    main()
```

Please do let me know the relative performance time with your 25 assets in 18.89 seconds! I'm very curious.

Comment: Though, if performance is really a very big issue, I'd suggest considering PyCurl. I've not used it myself, but it frequently comes up in the discussion of very high performance environments.

Answer (score 1):

I'd still recommend my other answer below(?) regarding the use of the requests module from a pure cleanliness perspective (requests is *very* clean to work with), but I recognize it may or may not address your original question.

If you want to try PyCurl, which likely *will* impact your original question, here's the same code implemented with that approach:

```
# Requires pycurl module be installed.:
# `pip install pycurl` or `pip3 install pycurl`
# https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycurl/7.43.0
# NOTE: The syntax used herein for pycurl is python 3 compliant.
# Not python 2 compliant.
import pycurl

import base64
import json
import csv

def pycurl_data( url, headers ):
    buffer = BytesIO()
    connection = pycurl.Curl()
    connection.setopt( connection.URL, url )
    connection.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, headers )
    connection.setopt( connection.WRITEDATA, buffer )
    connection.perform()
    connection.close()

    body = buffer.getvalue()
    # NOTE: The following assumes a byte string and a utf8 format. Change as desired.
    return json.loads( body.decode('utf8') )

# Count Number so that process only runs for 25 assets at a time will be
# replaced with a variable that is determined by the number of computers added
# to the list
Count_Stop = 25

final_output_list = []

def get_creds():
    # Credentials Function that retrieves username:pw from .file
    with open('.cred') as cred_file:
        cred_string = cred_file.read().rstrip()
        return cred_string
        print(cred_string)

def get_all_assets():
    # Function to retrieve computer ID + computer names and store the ID in a
    # new list called computers_parsed
    base_url = 'jss'
    what_we_want = 'JSSResource/computers'
    request_url = base_url + what_we_want

# NOTE the request_url is constructed based on your request assignment just below.
# As such, it is malformed as a URL, and I assume anonymized for your posting on SO.
#    request = urllib2.Request('jss'
#                              'JSSResource/computers')
#

    creds = get_creds()


    headers= [ 'Authorization: Basic ' + base64.b64encode(creds) ]
    response = pycurl_data( url, headers )


    # At this point the request for ID + name has been retrieved and now to be
    # formatted in json
    parsed_ids_json = json.dumps( response )
    # Then assign the parsed list (which has nested lists) at key 'computers'
    # to a new list variable called computer_set
    computer_set = parsed_ids_json['computers']
    # New list to store just the computer ID's obtained in Loop below
    computer_ids = []
    # Count variable, when equal to max # of computers in Count_stop it stops.
    count = 0
    # This for loop iterates over ID + name in computer_set and returns the ID
    # to the list computer_ids
    for computers in computer_set:
        count += 1
        computer_ids.append(computers['id'])
        # This IF condition allows for the script to be tested at 25 assets
        # instead of all 2,000+ (comment out other announce_all_assets call)
        if count == Count_Stop:
            announce_all_assets(computer_ids, count)
    # announce_all_assets(computer_ids, count)

def announce_all_assets(computer_ids, count):
    print('Final list of ID\'s for review: ' + str(computer_ids))
    print('Total number of computers to check against JSS: ' +
          str(count))
    extension_attribute_request(computer_ids, count)

def extension_attribute_request(computer_ids, count):
    # Creating new variable, first half of new URL used in loop to get
    # extension attributes using the computer ID's in computers_ids
    base_url = 'jss'
    what_we_want = '/subset/extensionattributes'
    creds = get_creds()
    print('Extension attribute function starts now:')
    for ids in computer_ids:
        request_url = base_url + str(ids) + what_we_want


        headers= [ 'Authorization: Basic ' + base64.b64encode(creds) ]
        response = pycurl_data( url, headers )

        parsed_ext_json = json.dumps( response )


        ext_att_json = parsed_ext_json['computer']['extension_attributes']
    retrieve_all_ext(ext_att_json)

def retrieve_all_ext(ext_att_json):
    new_computer = {}
    # new_computer['original_id'] = ids['id']
    # new_computer['original_name'] = ids['name']
    for computer in ext_att_json:
        new_computer[str(computer['name'])] = computer['value']
        add_to_master_list(new_computer)

def add_to_master_list(new_computer):
    final_output_list.append(new_computer)
    print(final_output_list)

def main():
    # Function to run the get all assets function
    get_all_assets()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Function to run the functions in order: main > get all assets >
    main()
```

Comment: Just a thought. I don't mean to presume you aren't fully familiar with your API, but on the off-chance... Might there be a mechanism through which you can request all computers _with_ extensionattributes in a single json return? That would go a _long_ way towards your solution. It may require calling multiple pages, but that would at least require fewer network interactions than polling each computer record individually. If there isn't such a mechanism, it might be worth implementing, or taking to whomever does the implementing as a suggestion.